# Any data set available for Twitter tweets classification?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, social-media, nlp

Is there any dataset available for different categories like music, politics, business etc which can be used to classify input tweets?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you looking for a dataset of tagged tweets to use for training?

Comment: @JoeGermuska: yeah, that is what I am saying.

Comment: Not sure why this was migrated here. Data set requests are considered off topic on this site. This belongs on the Open Data Stackexchange.

Comment: Do you have any language, geography, topic requirements (i.e. English, USA, general topics)?

Comment: @philshem: yes, US based English content

Answer (score 1):

The Streaming APIs
Overview
The Streaming APIs give developers low latency access to Twitter’s global stream of Tweet data. A proper implementation of a streaming client will be pushed messages indicating Tweets and other events have occurred, without any of the overhead associated with polling a REST endpoint.

If your intention is to conduct singular searches, read user profile information, or post Tweets, consider using the REST APIs instead.

Please refer the link: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/public